# AWS IAM Bool v/s BoolIfExists

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm unable to understand difference between `Bool` and `BoolIfExists` in AWS IAM policy condition. Can someone please explain?

ex:

```
"Condition" : {"BoolIfExists" : {"aws:MutliFactorAuthPresent" : false}}

"Condition" : {"Bool" : {"aws:MutliFactorAuthPresent" : false}}
```

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what's the difference?

Comment: @Marcin thank you! But they have used BoolIfExists with multifactorauthpresent https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/enforce-mfa-other-account-access-bucket/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, there is no such condition as `aws:MutliFactorAuthPresent`. It should be `aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent`. Second, `aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent` is **global key**, so its always exists. There is no reason to use `IfExists` for it.

Anyway, ou need remember that IAM condition keys (except global ones), are **resource specific**. For example, `ec2:InstanceType` applies only to EC2 instances, while `ec2:VolumeSize` works only with EBS volumes.

In addition, some IAM actions (e.g. `ec2:runinstance`)  require access to **multiple resources**, such as ec2 instance and ebs-volumes, etc.

Thus when you craft IAM statements with actions that operate on multiple resources, such as `ec2:runinstance`, and you want to make conditions, you may often get mismatch, because not all your condition keys apply to all resources that will be accessed.

For example, condition key `ec2:VolumeSize` does not apply to EC2 instance, but to EBS volumes. This fails because  of the [following](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition.html):

> A key that is not present in the request is considered a mismatch.

So you can use [...IfExists condition operator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html#Conditions_IfExists) to make sure that the there is no failure in such cases.

An [example of such IAM statement](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html#Conditions_IfExists) is:

```
        {
            "Sid": "RunInstance",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLikeIfExists": {
                    "ec2:InstanceType": [
                        "t1.*",
                        "t2.*",
                        "m3.*"
             ]}}
        }
```

Without `IfExists`, there will be a mismatch, because `ec2:RunInstances` requires access to EBS volumes, and the `ec2:InstanceType` key does not apply to the volumes.

Comment: `aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent` only exists in temporary credentials that support using MFA

Comment: Docs saying this `The aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent key is not present when an API or CLI command is called with long-term credentials, such as user access key pairs.`

Comment: This is patently false, and can lead to people creating very unsafe policy documents. Use `Bool` (true) when creating an `Allow` policy, `BoolIfExists` (false) when creating a `Deny` policy, then `aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent` is safe from credential types without MFA (i.e long-term credentials).

Answer (score 2):

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html

Recommended Combination

We recommend that you use the BoolIfExists operator to check whether a request is authenticated using MFA.

```
"Effect" : "Deny",
"Condition" : { "BoolIfExists" : { "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent" : "false" } }
```

This combination of Deny, BoolIfExists, and false denies requests that are not authenticated using MFA. Specifically, it denies requests from temporary credentials that do not include MFA. It also denies requests that are made using long-term credentials, such as AWS CLI or AWS API operations made using access keys. The *IfExists operator checks for the presence of the aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent key and whether or not it could be present, as indicated by its existence. Use this when you want to deny any request that is not authenticated using MFA. This is more secure, but can break any code or scripts that use access keys to access the AWS CLI or AWS API.

Answer (score 2):

`BoolIfExists` is a combination of the [`Bool`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html#Conditions_Boolean) and [`...IfExists`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html#Conditions_IfExists) condition operators. You can append `IfExists` onto any other condition operator, e.g. `StringLikeIfExists`.

So, given that `Bool` [means](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html#Conditions_Boolean):

> Boolean conditions let you construct Condition elements that restrict access based on comparing a key to "true" or "false."

And `...IfExists` [means](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html#Conditions_IfExists):

> If the policy key is present in the context of the request, process the key as specified in the policy. If the key is not present, evaluate the condition element as true.

We can interpret `BoolIfExists` to mean "If the boolean policy key exists, compare its value to `true` or `false`. If it doesn't exist, assume it evaluates to `true`."

Since your question referenced `aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent`, the [AWS blog post, *"How can I require MFA authentication for IAM users that use the AWS CLI?"*](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/mfa-iam-user-aws-cli/) may be of further help:

> The Boolean condition lets you restrict access with a key value set to true or false. You can add the IfExists condition operator to check if the MultiFactorAuthPresent key is present in the request. If the MultiFactorAuthPresent key isn't present, IfExists evaluates the condition element as true